# Generate a directory tree in python with self made class Treenode (Problem of recursion)

Tags: python, recursion, tree, parent-child

I wan to create a python script that print out a directory tree.
I'm aware there are tons of information about the topic, and many ways to achieve it.
Still, my problem really is about recursion.

In order to face the problem i choosed a OOP way:
Create a Class TreeNode
Store some props and methods
calling in the os.walk function (ya i know I can use pathlib or other libs.)
recursively create parent-child relationship of folders/files

First, the Class TreeNode:
properties: data, children, parent
methods: add_child(),
get_level(), to get the level of the parent/child relation in order to print it later
print_tree(), to actually print the tree (desired result shown above code)

```
class Treenode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None

    def add_child(self,child):
        child.parent = self
        self.children.append(child)

    def get_level(self):
        level = 0
        p = self.parent
        while p:
          level += 1
          p = p.parent

        return level

    def print_tree(self):
      spaces = " " * self.get_level() * 3
      prefix = spaces + "|__" if self.parent else ""
     
      print(prefix + self.data)
      for child in self.children:
          child.print_tree()
```

Second, the probelm. Function to creating the tree

```
def build_tree(dir_path):
  for root,dirs,files in os.walk(dir_path):
    if dir_path == root:
      for d in dirs:
        directory = Treenode(d)
        tree.add_child(directory)
      for f in files: 
        file = Treenode(f)
        tree.add_child(file)
      working_directories = dirs
    else: 
      for w in working_directories:
        build_tree(os.path.join(dir_path,w))
      return tree
```

Finally, the main method:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  tree = Treenode("C:/Level0") 
  tree = build_tree("C:/Level0")
  tree.print_tree()

  pass
```

The output of this code would be:

```
C:/Level0
   |__Level1
   |__0file.txt
   |__Level2
   |__Level2b
   |__1file1.txt
   |__1file2.txt
   |__Level3
   |__2file1.txt
   |__LEvel4
   |__3file1.txt
   |__4file1.txt
   |__2bfile1.txt
```

The desired output should be:

```
C:/Level0
   |__Level1
      |__Level2
         |__Level3
            |__LEvel4
               |__4file1.txt
            |__3file1.txt
         |__2file1.txt
      |__Level2b
         |__2bfile1.txt
      |__1file1.txt
      |__1file2.txt
  |__0file.txt
```

The problem lays in the tree.add_child(directory), since everytime the code get there it add the new directory (or file) as child of the same "root tree". Not in tree.children.children..etc
So here's the problem. How do i get that. The if else statement in the build_tree() function is probably unecessary, i was trying to work my way around but no luck.

I know it's a dumb problem, coming from a lack of proper study of algorithms and data structures..
If you will to help though, i'm here to learn ^^

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
def build_tree(parent, dir_path):
    child_list = os.listdir(dir_path)
    child_list.sort()

    for child in child_list:
        node = Treenode(child)
        parent.add_child(node)

        child_path = os.path.join(dir_path, child)
        if os.path.isdir(child_path):
            build_tree(node, child_path)
```

Then, for your main code, use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root_path = "C:/Level0"
    tree = Treenode(root_path)
    build_tree(tree, root_path)
    tree.print_tree()
```

The main change was to use `os.listdir` rather than `os.walk`.  The problem with `os.walk` is that it recursively walks the entire directory tree, which doesn't work well with the recursive `build_tree`, which wants to operate on a single level at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.walk`, but then don't use recursion, as you don't want to repeat the call to `os.walk`: one call gives all the data you need already. Instead use a dictionary to keep track of the hierarchy:

```
def build_tree(dir_path):
    helper = { dir_path: Treenode(dir_path) }
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path, topdown=True):
        for item in dirs + files:
            node = helper[os.path.join(root, item)] = Treenode(item)
            helper[root].add_child(node)
    return helper[dir_path]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tree = build_tree("C:/Level0")
    tree.print_tree()
```